# String Replace then Explode after

Tags: php, wordpress, wpallimport

I am running a script to import records from an XML (WP All Import). I can run custom functions whilst it imports to modify the data, one field comes in the following format:

19/06/2015 11:07

I have the following function successfully removing the **/**

```
function no_slash( $str ) {
   $str2 = str_replace( "/", "", $str );
   return $str3;
}
```

However, my explode function is failing to run on the newly created value in $str2 value. I end up with ARRAY as the value instead.

```
function no_slash( $str ) {
   $str2 = str_replace( "/", "", $str );
   $str3 = explode(" ",$str2);
   return $str3;
}
```

Comment: Explode creates an array. Presumably the calling code is treating the return value as a string. If you explain what you are trying to do, there will be a better way. php has good built in support for dates

Comment: `$dto = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', $str)`;

Comment: just add the output you'd like to get as you added input.

Comment: strtotime may also help